# Calling a new activity when threads running - IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: android

I am developing a game which so far has involved just two activities: a splash screen and a main activity. The main activity starts up a new thread which handles the drawing and game mechanics. So far the game has been working nicely. Now I have just added a new button for the purposes of viewing a "high scores" page in a new activity. So I set up an onClick handler and when the button is clicked I call the following code:

```
in = new Intent("android.intent.action.HIGH");
startActivity(in);
```

and in the high scores activity I have an [Ok] button which instigates the following:

```
back_but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{   
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        finish();
    }
});
```

When I click the button to view the high scores, the high scores activity starts up fine, unfortunately when I click the [Ok] button the program crashes with an IllegalThreadStateException.

Should I have stopped or paused the game thread in the main program before calling the new activity?

Comment: Please post how you are trying to stop the thread. You should let it finish by itself setting true a flag that breaks from the loop. Anyway, most likely you are calling `Thread.start` on a finished thread.

Comment: @Mister Smith: So far I am not even attempting to stop any thread - I was just leaving it running. Do I need to stop it before starting the new activity?

Comment: No. BTW, does logcat show any hint on the line it happens?

Comment: @Mister Smith: well done - I'm not very good with the debugger, but I managed to work out that a call was made to setRunning(false) which killed the thread. I didn't spot this before. I had been assuming that the thread was still up and running when we returned from the high scores activity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are welcome. Just remember not to stop threads using any of the deprecated method, they were not thread-safe. Read here for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html